# Найти div-ы, включающие в себя определенный класс. python selenium xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Есть верстка, в верстке div-ы, имеющие атрибут "class", но проблема в том, что в этом атрибуте, как правило, содержится не одно значение, а несколько (div class="class1 class2 class3..."  Необходимо найти дивы, атрибут "class" которых ВКЛЮЧАЕТ ИЛИ РАВНЯЕТСЯ определенному значению. 
То есть такой стандартный метод здесь не сработает:

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class2']")

Так как мне нужно найти дивы, которые включают в себя этот класс, но могут содержать и другие классы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'class2')]")
```